# mysql php table join

Tags: php, mysql

I am probably doing something stupid but have been working on this for a day and can't seem to find error.

I have a join of several tables.  When I print out the results using **print_r(mysql_fetch_array($res)**, I see a value for the field I want.  However, when I try to echo this out or otherwise get access to it, it seems to be empty.  Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?  Thanks in advance as this is driving me crazy.

tables (some fields omitted)

```
members
id|username|password|datetime|email
membercontact
id|memberid|contactid

php
$sql = "SELEcT m.*,mc.*,mc.contactid as mccon
from `members` m
LEFT JOIN `membercontact` mc
on m.id = mc.memberid
WHERE m.id = '147'"

$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
echo $row['contactid'];
echo $row['mccon']
}
```

output: nothing . I've also tried other ways to access the **contactid** field.  Other fields do print such as $row['password']

However when I use print_r on the results I can see following:

Array ( [0] => v [username] => v [1] => pass [password] => pass [2] => 147 [id] => 147 [3] => 2013-09-05 12:08:03 [datetime] => 2013-09-05 12:08:03 [4] => vz@aol.com [email] => v@aol.com  [19] => 933 [contactid] => 933  [20] => 147 [memberid] => 147 [24] => 933 [contactid] => 933 )

The only thing weird I notice is that some fields are repeated more than once, notably **contactid** though I cannot say why.  (The reason for the skips in numbers is there are a lot of other extraneous fields omitted.)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have used `LEFT JOIN` and if there is one to many relation you probably have to use `GROUP BY`

```
$sql = "SELEcT m.*,mc.*,mc.contactid as mccon
from `members` m
LEFT JOIN `membercontact` mc
on m.id = mc.memberid
WHERE m.id = '147'"
GROUP BY m.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELEcT m.*,mc.*,mc.contactid as mccon 
from `members` m,
`membercontact` mc
WHERE mc.memberid = m.id AND m.id = '147'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not join issue , its how you have selected the columns from each table. Check following source

```
<?php
 $query="select 'hame1' as name, 'name2' as name";
 $con = mysql_connect ('localhost','root','root',true) or die ('connection to db failed');
 mysql_select_db('test_db',$con);

 $res=mysql_query($query);
 if($res){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
      var_dump($row);   
    }   
 }else{
     echo mysql_error($con);
 }  

?>
```

Will output

```
array
  0 => string 'hame1' (length=5)
  'name' => string 'name2' (length=5)
  1 => string 'name2' (length=5)
```

You would argu why the hell three values if I had only fetch two . Its bcz the name for both column alias are same i.e `name`. If you want to fix the issue make sure your column name does not collide and `select only desired columns from each table that is efficient and readable also, if column names collide give it an alias` e.g

```
 $query="SELEcT m.column1,m.column2 ,mc.column1 as mc_column1 ...."
```